# I want to disable developer mode

Tags: magento2.2.2

how can i hide errors from main site ?

my **developer** mode is **off**

```
php bin/magento maintinance:disable
```

what can i do my site is not working.

By mistake i run the command

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

now it is showing error and overall site is not working .

Comment: rm -rf <magento.host>/var/di/* <magento.host>/var/generation/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change to developer or production mode, we clear the contents of **following directories**:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

**Exceptions**:

- `.htaccess` files are not removed
- `pub/static` contains a file that specifies the version of static
  content; this file is not removed

---

1. delete the contents of the `var/generation` and `var/di` directories:

   `rm -rf <magento.host>/var/di/* <magento.host>/var/generation/*`
2. Set the mode:

   `bin/magento deploy:mode:set {mode} [-s|--skip-compilation]`

Comment: no nothing changed :(

Comment: give the command you ran just now..

Comment: and check the mode please

Comment: bin/magento deploy:mode:show

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kz1i90

Comment: and current mode is developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83692/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-samair-ali).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 mode available in Magento

- Default
- Developer
- Production

As you can not switch from `Developer` to `Default`. You need to set `Production` mode By

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Comment: there is some issue when i run this command . some errors appear . i can not solve that ... so in short i just want to romove error logs from screen and make site running again

Comment: But in developer mode It will log error on front.You need to remove error and enable production mode.

Comment: i was not in developer mode before ... and there were no errors on screen obviously . by mistake i have started developer mode .. i just want to go back to production mode i dont know how to remove the error ...

Comment: what error you are getting when changing mode ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kz1cky